Quick uniform sampling with replacement
I seek to quickly uniformly sample $N$ items with replacement from a list $[a_1, a_2]$ of length $n=2$, and ideally for larger $n$ as well.
For the case of $n=2$, approaching this by summing binomial coefficients seems reasonable:

Choose a random integer $r \in [1, 2^N]$.
Find the minimum index $m$ to which to sum in order to reach $r$, i.e.,
$$m = {\text{min}}\left\{x \leq N \middle| \sum_{k=0}^x {N \choose k} \geq r\right\}.$$
Choose $r$ copies of $a_1$, and $N-r$ copies of $a_2$.

The idea here is that $k$ copies of $a_1$ can be sampled in $N \choose k$ ways, and in total there are $2^N$ possible sampling sequences.
Now the problem is in finding when the sum of binomial coefficients reaches $r$. Is there a quick way of doing this? Perhaps normal approximation could be used, but I would rather see an exact solution. If approximation indeed is the way to go, can the exact $m$ be searched in the neighbourhood of the approximated one without extensive summation?
Also, the general problem for $n>2$ is of particular interest.

For $n=2$, you're describing sampling from a binomial distribution; that Wikipedia page references this paper on sampling algorithms. For general $n$ you're instead sampling from a multinomial distribution.

Also note that if your first step is "choose a random integer $r\in [1,2^N]$", then you're generating an $N$-bit binary number ($r-1$) so you're essentially just simulating the sampling-with-replacement process.

@Karl Thank you for the links. Oh, this perspective makes the problem pretty much vanish. In the multinomial case the sampling appears to then be a n-ary number.

Yes, but generating an $N$-digit random number is the same as performing $N$ uniform samples, so this is not an efficient strategy - it's equivalent to just running the $N$-step simulation. A fast solution should use time and space closer to $\log N$.
